# .gitignore pattern to recurisvely ignore all files recursively, but not folders and not other .gitignore files

Tags: git, gitignore

At the moment, what I have might actually be what I need really, but I'm not sure if it's the most appropriate solution.

So let's say i have a folder called `logs`, and I want to gitignore anything in that file, APART from subfolders and their gitignore files -- the reason for this is basically that **I want to have in my commit history one file in each subfolder -- just the gitignore file and nothing else, so that when i `git pull` from a server, the `git pull` creates the sub-folders as required, but doesn't create any other files in those subfolders.**

So at the moment, I have my folder `logs` and I have a subfolder in that called `system_logs` and I have a subfolder in that called `admin_logs`. I can put this .gitignore file into each level of this directory tree:

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
```

and it seems to work at ignoring everything except subfolders and their .gitignore files. In other words it seems to be working.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note that directories are never directly represented in git but only exist as long as there is a file in them (sometimes a dummy file called something like `.gitempty` is used for this)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this?

Not really. You could have your software just *create* the `logs` directory and its subdirectories. That's neither specifically better nor specifically worse, just different.